# Make focus change sound in tvOS

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I'm programatically changing focus in a tvOS app in response to a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. This all works fine, except there the nice 'boop' sound that plays when changing focus normally doesn't play, which makes the user experience a bit odd. Is there a way to programatically play this sound, or is there some other way I should be trying to handle the focus change?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the button that is in focus have a background border in a different color or something.
In regards to sounds why don't you run a SKAction or play a AVFoundation file when changing focus.

You said you did all the focus stuff programmatically with gesture recognisers (I have done the same for my SpriteKit game) so I assume in the methods that get called when swiping you need to add the sound effect.

In my game those methods look something like this

```
func swipedRightTV() {
    if menuButton.isFocused {
         menuButton.isFocused = false 
         // play your sound here
         playButton.isFocused = true
    }
func swipeLeftTV() {       
    if playButton.isFocused {
         playButton.isFocused = false 
         // play your sound here
         menuButton.isFocused = true
    }
```

If I have more than 2 buttons I use more if/else if statements in the methods, for simplicity tho I just used 2 in the example.

Does this help or are your methods totally different?

Comment: I did something similar. Rather than using gesture recognizers I put two buttons off screen around the content. Whenever one of them gets focused I perform the action I used to with the gesture recognizer, but now I get the boop sounds!

Comment: cool, do you get the bloop sound automatically or did you use your own? I assume your app is not a spritekit game so some of the stuff you get for UIKit doesn't work with spriteKit. Can you download the official bloop sound somewhere?

Comment: Nope, just a normal UIKit app. The boop sound happens automatically when the UIButtons are focused, so no hackery needed.

Comment: nice, well SpritetKit its all DIY.